# How to stop fractions in display equations from running into each other?

Tags: amsmath, align, arrays, fractions

Is there some standard way to create multiple display equations like the following

[image]

without having to use:

1. `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}` (so that the two rows in the second equation don't get too close to each other)
2. `array` environment (so that I can use `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}`. Can't use the `align` environment again)
3. `\displaystyle` (so that things would be displayed the way they would if I used `align`)

as I've done below? My solution just seems like such a kludgy hack. There has to be a better/standard way...right?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}{
    \begin{align*}
      \pi(\mu \mid x) &= \frac{\pi(\mu)\,\mathcal{L}(x \mid \mu)}{p(x)} \\
                      &= \left\{
                            \begin{array}{lcl}
                              \displaystyle{\frac{(1-w)\phi(x)}{p(x)}}
                                & \mbox{for} & \mu = 0 \\
                              \displaystyle{\frac{w\gamma(\mu)\phi(x-\mu)}{p(x)}}
                                & \mbox{for} & \mu \neq 0. \\
                            \end{array}
                          \right.\\
    \end{align*}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` -- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#The_cases_environment ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `dcases` environment provided by the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package; this environment gives the same output as with `cases` (from `amsmath`) except that the rows are set in display style. A little example using the starred version `dcases*` in which the second column is set in font active just before the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \pi(\mu \mid x) &= \frac{\pi(\mu)\,\mathcal{L}(x \mid \mu)}{p(x)} \\
  &= \begin{dcases*}
    \frac{(1-w)\phi(x)}{p(x)} & for $\mu=0$. \\
    \frac{w\gamma(\mu)\phi(x-\mu)}{p(x)} &for $\mu\neq 0$.
   \end{dcases*}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know until I read your answer that the `dcases` environment of the `mathtools` package does such a good job of automatically setting the spacing between consecutive lines. Really neat!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get away from using an `array`, you could consider using the `cases` environment offered by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Also, there are other possibilities to `\arraystretch` and `\displaystyle`:

1. The new line macro `\\` of `array`s, `tabular`s or `cases` can take an optional length argument: `\\[<len>]` indicating the length skip between rows. Here `<len>` refers to any known TeX lenth unit.
2. Using `cases` leaves you free from `array` while still having the option to increase the "row skip" using Option 1. No need to specify a column alignment.
3. `amsmath` provides `\dfrac{<num>}{<denom>}` which is the `\displaystyle` form of `\frac{<num>}{<denom>}`.

All these combined in the following MWE is probably what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \pi(\mu \mid x) &= \frac{\pi(\mu)\,\mathcal{L}(x \mid \mu)}{p(x)} \\
                  &= \begin{cases}
                       \dfrac{(1-w)\phi(x)}{p(x)}
                         & \text{for $\mu=0$} \\[3ex]
                       \dfrac{w\gamma(\mu)\phi(x-\mu)}{p(x)}
                         & \text{for $\mu\neq 0$.}
                     \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

All of these features come standard with `amsmath`, so no need to load any additional packages. Also note the use of `\text` for text in math mode. This is another feature provided by `amsmath`.

Comment: Wonderfully helpful. Never knew about `\\[<len>]`. I followed up with a question on it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32789/3762).