# Length parameter for vertical skip space in a math environment?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, lengths, parameters

I learned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32743/how-to-stop-fractions-in-display-equations-from-running-into-each-other/32744#32744) that I can use `\\[<len>]` to explicitly set the vertical skip space between lines, e.g., `<len>` set to `3ex`. I'd like to set `<len>` to, say, 2-times the normal length in this environment (e.g., `align` or `dcases`) but I don't know the length parameter that determines this.

Another example: I'd like to change the explicit `3ex` below to some multiple of the vertical line-skip space in the `align` environment. Does anyone know what that is?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Some sample text
    \begin{spreadlines}{3ex}
      \begin{align*}
        \pi(\mu \mid x) &= \frac{\pi(\mu)\,\mathcal{L}(x \mid \mu)}{p(x)} \\
                        &= \begin{dcases*}
                             \frac{(1-w)\phi(x)}{p(x)} & for \(\mu=0\) \\
                             \frac{w\gamma(\mu)\phi(x-\mu)}{p(x)} & for \(\mu \neq 0\).
                           \end{dcases*}
      \end{align*}
    \end{spreadlines}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use multiples of `\baselineskip` and in tabulars/arrays `\normalbaselineskip`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadlines}{2\baselineskip}
  \begin{align*}
    \pi(\mu \mid x) &= \frac{\pi(\mu)\,\mathcal{L}(x \mid \mu)}{p(x)} \\[\normalbaselineskip]
                    &= \begin{dcases*}
                         \frac{(1-w)\phi(x)}{p(x)} & for \(\mu=0\) \\
                         \frac{w\gamma(\mu)\phi(x-\mu)}{p(x)} & for \(\mu \neq 0\).
                       \end{dcases*}
  \end{align*}
\end{spreadlines}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I noticed that using `2\baselineskip` instead of either `3ex` or `5\jot` shrinks the spacing between the `align` environment and the text immediately preceding it. I'm doing this in a `beamer` document so that might be driving this result.

Comment: then give a complete example not only a fragment of code

Comment: I completed the example I originally provided.

Comment: I cannot see it. With `\begin{spreadlines}{\normalbaselineskip}` i get no other spacing

Answer (score 3):

The linespacing in `align` and `gather` is defined by a length called `\jot`, though exactly what this value represents, I don't know.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{gather}
    a = b \\
    c = d
  \end{gather}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{gather}
    a = b \\[2\jot]
    c = d
  \end{gather}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

Comment: `\jot` represents a length for adjusting the spacing: the default is to add `1\jot` to the baseline skip.