# Even vertical spacing in multline and gather environments

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, multline

Using fractions or expressions with sub- and superscripts may lead to uneven vertical spacing in math environments spanning several lines (i.e., `align`, `gather`, `multline`,...). A fix for `align` was presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55180/18321). Is there a similar solution for `multline` and/or `gather`?

This MWE illustrates the problem. The spacing after the first line is larger than after the second due to the sum + subscripts.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[bt]{0.35\linewidth}
  \begin{multline*}
    x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_n\\
    +y_1+y_2+z_3\\
    +z_1+z_2+z_3
  \end{multline*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like to use `\textstyle\sum\limits_{}^{}` to get a better size for the sum sign. But this is my preference.

Comment: It's not related to the problem in the referenced question, there large entries were tight to the surrounding rows and the answer made sure that the spacing strut _in those rows_ was larger than the entry thus preserving row separation but making the row separation _more_ variable. It would not do anything here as the later rows are not large. Here (I think) you are trying to normalise the distance between baselines not maintain a separation between rows. that would mean analysing all rows of the display which is harder. I'd just use `\setlength\jot{1.5ex}` or `spreadlines` from `mathtools`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right. I'm sorry, I should have tried my example first. I assumed the mechanism was the same, which was obviously wrong...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- i think you get this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to the problem in the referenced question, there large entries were tight to the surrounding rows and the answer made sure that the spacing strut in those rows was larger than the entry thus preserving row separation but making the row separation more variable. It would not do anything here as the later rows are not large.

Here (I think) you are trying to normalise the distance between baselines not maintain a separation between rows. that would mean analysing all rows of the display which is harder. I'd just use

```
\setlength\jot{1.5ex}
```

or

```
\begin{spreadlines}{1em}
```

from

`mathtools`