# What is the best way to space an equation?

Tags: spacing, equations, formatting

Recently I have chosen to change the typical way of writing in math mode for one in which before certain operators or symbols there is a space in between (think about `arrows`, `=`, `:`, etc.).

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Normal writing: \[x+2=0\Rightarrow x=-2.\]

Own writing: \[\begin{matrix}x+2 & = & 0 && \Rightarrow && x & = & -2.\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of writing]

Another example:

```
\[\begin{matrix}
\begin{cases}y\quad=&xk_1,\; k_1\in\mathbb Z\\z\quad=&xk_2,\; k_2\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}
&\Rightarrow&
y+z&=&xk_1+xk_2
&\Rightarrow&
y+z=x\underbrace{(k_1+k_2)}_{k_3\in\mathbb Z}&\Rightarrow&
y+z=xk_3
&\Rightarrow&
x\mid y+z.
\end{matrix}\]
```

Note that it produces an extra alignment message but the point is that I don't want to manually set space to not make that mistake again.

I use `matrix` environment because:

- it's easy to program;
- automatic centering when the `\\` command is used;
- requires a single package to work.

Anyway, when there are certain types of equations keeping them centered it becomes a bit visually annoying. In addition, I use a personalized space for each environment (not a general number):

```
Example 1: \[\begin{matrix}x+2+1+52&=&2\\y&=&2\\z&=&1\end{matrix}\]

Example 2 (same as Example 1 but with vertical space): \[\def\arraystretch{1.5}\begin{matrix}x+2+1+52&=&2\\y&=&2\\z&=&1\end{matrix}\]

Example 3 (with more vertical space): \[\def\arraystretch{3.0}\begin{matrix}\displaystyle\int_2^2{x\;\text dx}&=&2+\dfrac x2\\\displaystyle\int_2^2{x\;\text dx}&=&2+\dfrac x2\end{matrix}\]
```

[image: Spacing example]

Note that I typed manually the convenient array strecth to match the other spaces as best as possible. I do it for every equation in the document...

Also in a `matrix` environment there could be more substructures, such as `cases`,`array`, etc.

**I would like to know if there is any environment that does this work or how it could be automated as best as possible to keep the horizontal spaces vertical (maybe using a personalized command, maybe a package, etc.).**

Any kind of contribution is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but if you want to change "normal writing" of math into "something unreadable", I don't feel like spending my own time helping you to do that!

Comment: Thank you for answering! I don't know if is a "something unreadable" change. Think about in a five or six lines of integrals; there are very tight!

Comment: Honestly I agree the result is very unreadable. However, consider that all the spacing LaTeX inserts is based on some configurable lengths, so instead of ad-hoc hacking with matrices, you could look into how relations and operators are spaced (`\mathrel`, `\mathbin` etc) and the corresponding vertical lengths

Comment: The `tabstackengine` package allows things to be set with a uniform vertical gap (see "short stacks" in `stackengine` package documentation), and with math tabbing with customized horizontal spacing.  What it won't allow is the numbering of individual equations.  See http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine/stackengine.pdf, http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tabstackengine/tabstackengine.pdf.

Comment: For people coming across this, the "keep same space across all type" is [math mode - Vertical Spacing within align environment accounting for fractions - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54587/vertical-spacing-within-align-environment-accounting-for-fractions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tabstackengine` package allows things to be set with a uniform vertical gap (see "short stacks" in `stackengine` package documentation), and with math tabbing with customized horizontal spacing. What it won't allow is the numbering of individual equations.

I created `\CtabbedShortstack` to mean *centered* `\tabbedShortstack`, as the packages `\Centerstack`, `\Vectorstack` and `\Matrixstack` employ "long stacks" which have a constant baselineskip, rather than a constant gap.

In the MWE below, there is a 12pt gap between equations, and an *extra* 7pt of horizontal gap added to the horizontal spacing around tabs.  Because the OP's example seemed to show it, I retained centered alignment of columns, rather than something akin to `align` (which in this case would be `rcl` alignment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\setstackgap{S}{12pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{7pt}
\TABbinary
\newcommand\CtabbedShortstack[2][c]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\tabbedShortstack[#1]{#2}}%
  \vcenter{\box0}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent Example 2:
\[
  \tabbedShortstack{
  x + 2 + 1 + 52 &=& 2\\
  y &=& 2\\
  z &=& 1
  }
\]
Example 3:
\[
  \tabbedShortstack{
  \int_2^2 x \,dx &=& 2 + \frac{x}{2}\\
  \int_2^2 x \,dx &=& 2 + \frac{x}{2}
  }
\]
First in stack numbered
\begin{equation}
  \tabbedShortunderstack{
  x + 2 + 1 + 52 &=& 2\\
  \int_2^2 x \,dx &=& 2 + \frac{x}{2}
  }
\end{equation}
Last in stack numbered
\begin{equation}
  \tabbedShortstack{
  \int_2^2 x \,dx &=& 2 + \frac{x}{2}\\
  x + 2 + 1 + 52 &=& 2
  }
\end{equation}
Middle of stack numbered
\begin{equation}
  \CtabbedShortstack{
  \int_2^2 x \,dx &=& 2 + \frac{x}{2}\\
  \int_2^2 x \,dx &=& 2 + \frac{x}{2}
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]