# Boxing 4 equations with a thin gap

Tags: math-mode, equations

Currently i have.

```
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
\begin{split}
EQUATION1 \\

\\
EQUATION2 \\
\\ 
EQUATION3  \\
\\
EQUATION4
   }
\end{equation*}
```

However the gap inbetween looks ridiculous and would like a smaller one, is this possible?

Comment: Related Question: [Length parameter for vertical skip space in a math environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32789/length-parameter-for-vertical-skip-space-in-a-math-environment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By putting extra newlines (`\\`) it is expected to get extra vertical spaces between the equations. Simply remove the extra `\\` and complete as this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
\begin{split}
y = x^2 + x -2 \\[-.1cm] % adjust the value as you wish
y = x^2 + x -2 \\[-.1cm]
y = x^2 + x -2  \\[-.1cm]
y = x^2 + x -2
\end{split}
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

The output then is:

[image]

Comment: But is it possible to have a smaller gap. I want a gap just maybe half a line or so. Simply because exponents and subscripts are a little close otherwise.

Comment: Sure, this is possible by controlling the option of newlines. See my updated answer.